# Best way to get value of an button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get the value of the `value` attribute of the `button` element and write this value into another modal.

I have a loop in my PHP which writes the following HTML:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn" value="1">Confirm</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn" value="2">Confirm</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn" value="3">Confirm</button>
```

When I click on a button it shows a modal with two buttons, one to continue and one to cancel. I want store the value of the `value` attribute of the first button in the `href` attribute of the "continue" button in the second modal.

My modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="i-circle danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
        <h4>Are you sure?!</h4>
        <p>If yes click on Continue!</p>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a href="IWANTGETIDHERE">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://stuff.wp-dreams.com/modal/) is a demo of my modal.

Comment: How do you show the `modal` post your code here.

Comment: You have no id in your buttons.

Comment: If i have an id, and getelementbyid, i cant get value of each button, only from the first one, but i need know all values in my modal. So my modal need be dynamic and use value of button who was click and call the modal.

Comment: You can use a `data-customId`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha can you show the javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Instead of alert, use:

```
$('.modal-footer a').attr("href", $(this).attr("value"));
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Un4/)

**Using Pure Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', this.value);
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q57A3/)

Comment: But i have many others buttons using this class, because its from Twitter Bootstrap, can i get by name? and using pure javascript?

Comment: No problem because this code get the value of button clicked.

Comment: @user1533106 I hope the help you.

Comment: @user1533106 Nifty Modal Window is rock. I don't know but I do not know, I'll to use, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
button = document.getElementById("buttonID");
button.onclick = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].href =  document.getElementById("buttonID").value
}
```

If you are looking for no dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, add a `data-customId` attribute and remove the `value` from all of your buttons:

```
<button data-customId="1" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn">Confirm</button>
<button data-customId="2" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn">Confirm</button>
<button data-customId="3" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#mod-error" type="button" class="myclasses btn" >Confirm</button>
```

Also, add an `id` to your `modal div` like:

```
<div id='confirmAction' class="modal-body">
    <!-- Markup -->
</div>
```

Then register a handler for `bootstrap show event`:

```
$('#confirmAction').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-customId'); // Get the customId
    $(this).find('a:first').attr('href', $id);
});
```

Comment: I cant select two anwsers, sorry!